# My WordPress thumbnails are way larger (in bytes) than the original

Tags: wordpress

I'm new to WordPress and working with a site that I've inherited. The site has 2 screenshots on the main page, managed as a Gallery from the Advanced Custom Fields plugin.

Both screenshots are originally 2880x1996 PNG files that clock in at 460 KB each. WordPress generates thumbnails of these screenshots, and at runtime it's serving the 1920x1331 PNG thumbnail... Which is 1.6 MB in size!

Shouldn't the lower resolution image be smaller in size? How do I get WordPress to do a better job with thumbnail generation, or perhaps just disable it for this image?

Comment: Answers on this forum are normally only supported for programmable related questions and this question does ask for opinion based answers; however I want you to web search for some plugins which will 'reduce image file size in wordpress'. There are a number of good plugins out there to assist.

Comment: check this [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/249150/thumbnails-are-bigger-in-size-than-the-original-image)

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I made some code changes to fix this.  First was to define a new image size 'original' in my functions.php.  I omitted the dimensions which appear to have caused WordPress to serve up the original image and not one of the inefficiently resized images:

```
add_image_size( 'original', '', '', true );
```

Next, I updated the theme to reference 'original' as the image size where it was previously referencing 'large'.

To take it further, I also used pngquant to shrink the image sizes.  The 460 KB original was reduced down to 242 KB, which seems pretty good for a 2880x1996 image.